# SQL Insert Into New Table from Old Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I've got two table which are near identical, the only difference is the newer one has different field names. Basically the old table was outdated and needed to be re-worked; I'm trying to extract all the field where the VendorNumber = Vendor_ID all the field that are being copied to are guaranteed empty.

The below SQL code if very large, but it's the best I could use for it...

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO tbleVendorData (EDIContact,EDIPhone,EDIEmail,EDIPlatform,EDIStatus,EDIMigrationStatus,EDIMigrationDate,TesterName,TestStartDate,LastContactDate," & _
                  "CompletionStatus850,CompletionStatus856,CompletionStatus810C,CompletionStatus810F,CompletionStatusMH10,CompletionStatusPTicket,TestingNotes," & _
                  "TestingStatus850,TestingStatus855,TestingStatus856,TestingStatus810C,TestingStatus810F,GoLiveDate850,GoLiveDate855,GoLiveDate856," & _
                  "GoLiveDate810C,GoLiveDate810F,VendorKickOffDate,Exemption,ExemptionStartDate,ExemptionEndDate,ExemptionReason," & _
                  "ExemptionDescription,Ownership,NECC2500,NECC3500,NECC5000,NECC10000,NECCStartDate,NECCEndDate,SPSCertificate,ProductionStatus850," & _
                  "ProductionStatus855,ProductionStatus856,ProductionStatus810C,ProductionStatus810F,PlatformFI850,PlatformFI855,PlatformFI856," & _
                  "PlatformFI810C,PlatformFI810F,ProductionDate850,ProductionDate855,ProductionDate856,ProductionDate810C,ProductionDate810F," & _
                  "ProductionPrepack,ProductionCrossDock,ProductionMultiStyle,ProductionProductAttribute,ProductionMasterPack,ProductionCrossDockMix," & _
                  "ProductionStandAloneMix,ProductionLegalEntity,FirstASNDate,FirstINVDate,SALeadDays,CrossDockLeadDays,CommunicationNotes,ProductionNotes," & _
                  "QU1,QU2,ISA_ID1,ISA_ID2,GS_ID1,GS_ID2,VAN,VAN2,HYBRID) " & _
           "SELECT EDI_Contact_Name,EDI_Contact_Phone,EDI_Contact_Email,Platform,Status,Migration_Status,Migration_Date,Tester,Testing_Start_Date,Last_Contact," & _
                  "Status_850,Status_856,Status_810C,Status_810F,Status_MH10_Label,Status_PTicket,Tnotes,TS_850,TS_855,TS_856,TS_810C,TS_810F,GLD_850,GLD_855," & _
                  "GLD_856,GLD_810C,GLD_810F,Kick_Off_Mtg,Exemption,Exemption_Start_Date,Exemption_End_Date,Exemption_Text,Exemption_Reason,Ownership," & _
                  "NECC_2500,NECC_3500,NECC_5000,NECC_10000,NECC_Start_Date,NECC_End_Date,SPS_Certificate,PS_850,PS_855,PS_856,PS_810C,PS_810F,P850_FI,P855_FI," & _
                  "P856_FI,P810C_FI,P810F_FI,PDTS_850,PDTS_855,PDTS_856,PDTS_810C,PDTS_810F,Prepack,Cross_Dock,[M-style],PCA,Master_Pack,[XD-Mix],[SA-Mix],Legal_Entity," & _
                  "First_ASN,First_INV,Lead_Days,Cross_Dock_Lead_Days,CNotes,Info,QU1,QU2,ISA_ID1,ISA_ID2,GS_ID1,GS_ID2,VAN,VAN2,HYBRID " & _
             "FROM tbleVendorRecord " & _
            "WHERE tbleVendorRecord.Vendor_ID = VendorNumber "
```

I am using MS Access in VBA and trying to run the above script I get the "Enter Paramter Value" for VendorNumber any idea why this is?

[image]

**EDIT:**

[image]

Comment: Look at your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I did and it looks fine to me... VendorNumber is correct

Comment: Doesn't look like it's correct to me. As Access is hinting to you, what is the value behind VendorNumber? It doesn't appear to be a column in your select statement, or a variable, or anything at all other than the word VendorNumber. What value should the engine use to compare if it's not coming from a column you have specified? SQL (nor I) know the answer, so you get a prompt.

Comment: `VendorNumber` is the first column in `tbleVendorData`, I just double checked the labels and it all matches... I've tried swapping it so that it looks like `WHERE tbleVendorRecord.Vendor_ID= VendorNumber ` and still giving me the same error

Comment: @Maldred - is the destination table (`tbleVendorData`) already loaded with the IDs of the vendor whose data you want to pull from the source table (`tbleVendorRecord`)?

Comment: You cannot reference a field in a table if the table is not itself referenced in query. In `SELECT,` no where does *tbleVendorData* appear. In append queries, the `SELECT` portion does not see `INSERT INTO`

Comment: @STLDeveloper Yes it is, they both have the exact number of records. tbleVendorData.VendorNumbers all equal the same number of records (and values) as tbleVendorRecord.Vendor_ID. I just need all the data moved from tbleVendorRecord to tbleVendorData with the matching ID numbers

Comment: @Maldred - You need an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT`.

Comment: @STLDeveloper Ooooh ok, I was using the wrong method then... Sorry I am not very knowledgeable with SQL. So, I was looking a little deeper here and I noticed that a JOIN might work here or even an INNER JOIN. Would using an UPDATE or JOIN be more beneficial?

Comment: @Maldred, see my answer, below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the destination table is *already loaded* with the IDs of the vendors whose records you want to store there, you need to update those records rather than insert new records.  Therefore, your query must select rows from the source table joined to the destination table on the vendor ID.

```
SQL = "UPDATE tbleVendorData " & _
      "SET EDIContact = s.EDI_Contact_Name, EDIPhone = s.EDI_Contact_Phone, EDIEmail = EDI_Contact_Email, EDIPlatform = s.Platform, EDIStatus = s.Status," & _
          "EDIMigrationStatus = s.Migration_Status, EDIMigrationDate = s.Migration_Date, TesterName = s.Tester, TestStartDate = s.Testing_Start_Date, " & _
          "LastContactDate = s.Last_Contact, CompletionStatus850 = s.Status_850, CompletionStatus856 = s.Status_856, CompletionStatus810C = s.Status_810C, " & _
          "CompletionStatus810F = s.Status_810F, CompletionStatusMH10 = s.Status_MH10_Label, CompletionStatusPTicket = s.Status_PTicket, TestingNotes = s.Tnotes, " & _
          "TestingStatus850 = s.TS_850, TestingStatus855 = s.TS_855, TestingStatus856 = s.TS_856, TestingStatus810C = s.TS_810C, TestingStatus810F = s.TS_810F, " & _
          "GoLiveDate850 = s.GLD_850, GoLiveDate855 = s.GLD_855, GoLiveDate856 = s.GLD_856, GoLiveDate810C = s.GLD_810C, GoLiveDate810F = s.GLD_810F, " & _
          "VendorKickOffDate = s.Kick_Off_Mtg, Exemption = s.Exemption, ExemptionStartDate = s.Exemption_Start_Date, ExemptionEndDate = s.Exemption_End_Date, " & _
          "ExemptionReason = s.Exemption_Text, ExemptionDescription = s.Exemption_Reason, Ownership = s.Ownership, NECC2500 = s.NECC_2500, NECC3500 = s.NECC_3500, " & _
          "NECC5000 = s.NECC_5000, NECC10000 = s.NECC_10000, NECCStartDate = s.NECC_Start_Date, NECCEndDate = s.NECC_End_Date, SPSCertificate = s.SPS_Certificate, " & _
          "ProductionStatus850 = s.PS_850, ProductionStatus855 = s.PS_855, ProductionStatus856 = s.PS_856, ProductionStatus810C = s.PS810C, " & _
          "ProductionStatus810F = s.PS_810F, PlatformFI850 = s.P850_FI, PlatformFI855 = s.P855_FI, PlatformFI856 = s.P856_FI, PlatformFI810C = s.P810C_FI, " & _
          "PlatformFI810F = s.P810F_FI, ProductionDate850 = s.PDTS_850,ProductionDate855 = s.PDTS_855,ProductionDate856 = s.PDTS_856, ProductionDate810C = s.PDTS_810C, " & _
          "ProductionDate810F = s.PDTS_810F, ProductionPrepack = s.Prepack, ProductionCrossDock = s.Cross_Dock, ProductionMultiStyle = s.[M-style], " & _
          "ProductionProductAttribute = s.PCA, ProductionMasterPack = s.Master_Pack, ProductionCrossDockMix = s.[XD-Mix], ProductionStandAloneMix = s.[SA_Mix], " & _
          "ProductionLegalEntity = s.Legal_Entity, FirstASNDate = s.First_ASN, FirstINVDate = s.First_INV, SALeadDays = s.Lead_Days, CrossDockLeadDays = s.Cross_Dock_Lead_Days, " & _
          "CommunicationNotes = s.CNotes, ProductionNotes = s.Info," & _
          "QU1 = s.QU1, QU2 = s.QU2, ISA_ID1 = s.ISA_ID1, ISA_ID2 = s.ISA_ID2, GS_ID1 = s.GS_ID1, GS_ID2 = s.GS_ID2, VAN = s.VAN, VAN2 = s.VAN2, HYBRID = s.HYBRID " & _
       "FROM " & _
          "(SELECT EDI_Contact_Name,EDI_Contact_Phone,EDI_Contact_Email,Platform,Status,Migration_Status,Migration_Date,Tester,Testing_Start_Date,Last_Contact," & _
                  "Status_850,Status_856,Status_810C,Status_810F,Status_MH10_Label,Status_PTicket,Tnotes,TS_850,TS_855,TS_856,TS_810C,TS_810F,GLD_850,GLD_855," & _
                  "GLD_856,GLD_810C,GLD_810F,Kick_Off_Mtg,Exemption,Exemption_Start_Date,Exemption_End_Date,Exemption_Text,Exemption_Reason,Ownership," & _
                  "NECC_2500,NECC_3500,NECC_5000,NECC_10000,NECC_Start_Date,NECC_End_Date,SPS_Certificate,PS_850,PS_855,PS_856,PS_810C,PS_810F,P850_FI,P855_FI," & _
                  "P856_FI,P810C_FI,P810F_FI,PDTS_850,PDTS_855,PDTS_856,PDTS_810C,PDTS_810F,Prepack,Cross_Dock,[M-style],PCA,Master_Pack,[XD-Mix],[SA-Mix],Legal_Entity," & _
                  "First_ASN,First_INV,Lead_Days,Cross_Dock_Lead_Days,CNotes,Info,QU1,QU2,ISA_ID1,ISA_ID2,GS_ID1,GS_ID2,VAN,VAN2,HYBRID " & _
             "FROM tbleVendorRecord JOIN tbleVendorData ON tbleVendorRecord.VendorID = tbleVendorData.VendorNumber) s"
```

Comment: Tried copy pasting this and I had to add a few SQL = SQL & in there because it said I had too many line continuations; however this is giving me a script error... I'll post a picture in my question above

Comment: Yes, it is very long.  Perhaps you could instead delete all the existing empty records you put into tbleVendorData and then simply do a simpler `INSERT` statement.

Comment: I don't think I can, since the variable names and order has changed

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem.  Simply specify the `SELECT` statement with the field names in the same order as the destination table.  They do not have to have the same field names, but they do need to be in the same order.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify which column from the old table will be inserted into the new table columns, and also you need to put **VALUES** at your query:

SQL = "INSERT INTO tbleVendorData (EDIContact,EDIPhone........) " & _
           "**VALUES (** SELECT EDI_Contact_Name **as EDIContact**,EDI_Contact_Phone **as EDIPhone**.... " & _
             "FROM tbleVendorRecord " & _
            "WHERE tbleVendorRecord.Vendor_ID = VendorNumber **)** "

Comment: You don't need to alias the colums to the same name, the column order of insert and select statements takes care of the mapping.